# Why is $x^5+x^4-x-1=(x-1)(x+1)^2(x^2+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

How can I prove $x^5+x^4-x-1=(x-1)(x+1)^2(x^2+1)$ by polynomial division? I see that $x=1$ is a zero of the denominator, but how do I get the other factors? Our professor said polynomial division, but I don't see it.

BTW, I know how to get the solution with the binomial formula: \begin{align*}
x^5+x^4-x-1 & = (x^5 - x) + (x^4 - 1)\\
& = x(x^4 - 1) + (x^4 - 1)\\
& = (x + 1)(x^4 - 1)\\
& = (x+1)(x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1)\\
& =(x+1)^2(x^2 + 1)(x - 1)\\
& = \cdots
\end{align*}

But I want to know another way to obtain the result.

Comment: Did you try doing polynomial long division on it to see what you're left with when you factor out $x-1$? You can also do some law of signs to help isolate roots.

Comment: For another path, try applying the rational root theorem.

Comment: @user170231 how do I apply this here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams we haven't done this. it should be possible by the normal polynom division

Comment: Those should be the same with a slightly different name.

Comment: user, you seem to be avoiding doing polynomial division, which is quite straightforward, and is also brief enough once you note that both $1$ and $-1$  are roots  of the denominator. Divide the denominator by $(x^2 -1)$   and the resulting cubic  still has $1$ a root. ......

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ then $p(x) = (x-\alpha)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ which you can find dividing $p(x)$ by $x-\alpha$.

Comment: This isn't really about #fractions, since you're leaving the numerator alone for now and just factoring the denominator.  So I'll change the tag to #factoring and edit the question to refer only to the denominator that you're trying to factor.  Let me know if you think this is missing something.

Comment: The factorization should be $(x+1)^2(x-1)(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;x^5+x^4-x-1 = x^4(x+1) - (x+1) = (x+1)(x^4 - 1) = \ldots$

Comment: I agree with @J.G

Comment: @dxiv That factorization it's already in the question.

Comment: @jjagmath Right, but it's arrived at using a different grouping. There is only so many ways you can get the same factorization.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform polynomial division? or how to decide what to try to divide by?  (The main answer to the second question is the Rational-Root Theorem, although there are some other ways to narrow it down.  But you'd still want to try $ x = 1 $ and $ x = - 1 $, which are all that you need in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^5+x^4-x-1)|_{x=-1}=5(-1)^4+4(-1)^3-1=0$, but $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^5+x^4-x-1)|_{x=-1}=20(-1)^3+12(-1)^2-1\neq 0$, this implies that $x=-1$ is a root of multiplicity two, so $(x-1)^2$ divides $x^5+x^4-x-1$, and as you point out $x=1$ is a root, then $(x+1)(x-1)^2=x^3+x^2-x-1$ divides $x^5+x^4-x-1$. If you use polynomial division $x^5+x^4-x-1\div x^3+x^2-x-1$ easily, you get that the remaining factor is $x^2+1$

Answer (score 3):

Another approach
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\ x^5+x^4\ }^{(x+1)x^4}\overbrace{\,-x-1\ \vphantom{x^4}}^{(x+1)(-1)}
&=(x+1)\left(x^4-1\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=(x+1)\left(x^2-1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)\tag{1b}\\
&=(x+1)(x+1)(x-1)\left(x^2+1\right)\tag{1c}\\
&=(x-1)(x+1)^2\left(x^2+1\right)\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ Note that $x+1$ is a factor
$\text{(1b):}$ $u^2-1=(u-1)(u+1)$ with $u=x^2$
$\text{(1c):}$ $u^2-1=(u-1)(u+1)$ with $u=x$
$\text{(1d):}$ reorganize

Answer (score 2):

If we want proceed by long division for the root $x=1$ we obtain

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrrrr}& x^5 & x^4 & x^3 & x^2 & x^1 & x^0 \\ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\ {\color{red}1} & \downarrow & 1 & 2 & 2 &2 &1\\ \hline & 1 & 2 & 2 &  2 &1&|\phantom{-} {\color{blue}0} \end{array}$$

that is

$$x^5+x^4-x-1=(x-1)(x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1)$$

and for $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1$ for the root $x=-1$ we obtain

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrrr}&  x^4 & x^3 & x^2 & x^1 & x^0 \\  & 1 & 2 & 2& 2 & 1\\ {\color{red}{-1}} & \downarrow  & -1 & -1 &-1 &-1\\ \hline  & 1 & 1 &  1 &1&|\phantom{-} {\color{blue}0} \end{array}$$

that is

$$x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1=(x+1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)$$

and for $x^3+x^2+x+1$ for the root $x=-1$ we obtain

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrr}&  x^3 &  x^2 & x^1 & x^0 \\   & 1 & 1& 1 & 1\\ {\color{red}{-1}} & \downarrow   & -1 &0 &-1\\ \hline   & 1 &  0 &1&|\phantom{-} {\color{blue}0} \end{array}$$

that is

$$x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$$

and finally

$$x^5+x^4-x-1=(x-1)(x+1)^2(x^2+1)$$

---

More directly recognizing by inspection $x=1$ and $x=-1$ as roots

$$\begin{array}{rrrrrr|ll} x^5 & x^4 & & & -x & -1   & x^2  -  1  
\\   -x^5 &  & x^3 &  & & &  x^3 +x^2+x+1
\\ \hline     & x^4 & x^3 & & -x &-1
\\ & \phantom{-}-x^4 &  &x^2 & & & 
\\ \hline  & & x^3 & x^2&-x&-1  
\\ & &-x^3  & & x& 
\\ \hline & &   & x^2& &-1 
\\ & &  &-x^2 & &+1 
\\ \hline & &   & & &
\end{array}$$

that is

$$x^5+x^4-x-1=(x+1)(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)$$

and since $(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)$

we have

$$x^5+x^4-x-1=(x+1)^2(x-1)(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Great LaTex skills!

Comment: @NoChance Thanks! I've used the examles indicated [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21096/505767)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to solve it, without polynomial divisions.

- By inspection, two of the roots are $\,1\,$ and $\,-1\,$.
- Also by inspection, the derivative $\,5 x^4 + 4 x^3 - 1\,$ has $\,-1\,$ as a root, so $\,-1\,$ is a double root.
- By [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the remaining two roots $\,a,b\,$ must satisfy $\, 1 + 2 \cdot (-1) + a + b = -1\,$ $\iff a+b=0\,$ and $\, 1 \cdot (-1)^2 \cdot ab = 1 \iff ab = 1\,$, so the quadratic factor is $\,x^2 + 1\,$.